# Getting no output using Apriori Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, apriori

My Dataframe:

```
number  assignment_group    short_description   Issue Labels
Req123  Support             TP issue         Battery Failure
```

My code:

Converting the data frame into lists

```
observations = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    observations.append([str(df1.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,10)])
```

Fitting the data to the algorithm

```
from apyori import apriori
associations = apriori(observations, min_length = 2, min_support = 0.2, min_confidence = 0.2, min_lift = 3)
```

Converting the associations to lists

```
associations = list(associations)
print(associations)
```

Getting no output when returning this.

Comment: What is `df1` and its `values`? Can I assume they are items written in strings?

Comment: Updated the Dataframe, It was both numeric and string data

Comment: Are they in a `numpy` array?

Comment: the data is in pandas dataframe, mostly having ticket data

Comment: As I answered, try lower hyper parameters.

Comment: Thank you too, buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what your `df1.values` really are, however, with

```
df1 = [
    'Aa', 'Aa', 'Aa', 'Aa', 'Aa',
    'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee', 'Ff',
]

observations = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    observations.append([str(df1[i][j]) for j in range(0, 2)])
```

the following code works.

```
from apyori import apriori
associations = apriori(
    observations,
    min_length = 2,
    min_support = 0.2,
    min_confidence = 0.2,
    min_lift = 2
)

associations = list(associations)
print(associations)
```

The output is:

```
[
    RelationRecord(
        items=frozenset({'a', 'b'}), 
        support=0.5, 
        ordered_statistics=[
            OrderedStatistic(
                items_base=frozenset({'a'}),       
                items_add=frozenset({'b'}),
                confidence=1.0,
                lift=2.0
            ), 
            OrderedStatistic(
                items_base=frozenset({'b'}),
                items_add=frozenset({'a'}),
                confidence=1.0,
                lift=2.0
            )
        ]
    )
]
```

I only changed `min_lift` from 3 to 2. When it was 3, the output was empty.

Apriori algorithm is to find frequent item sets as association rules between each set. How frequent and the length of item sets are tuned by hyper parameters. So try different hyper parameters and see what you get.

Comment: Can we get the output in a tabular/dataframe manner?